# Count total number of array inside while loop

Tags: count

Count the array.

> Array ( [0] => 4 [id] => 4 [1] => 2019-2020 [fyear] => 2019-2020 [2] => 01-04-2019 [start_date] => 01-04-2019 [3] => 31-03-2020 [end_date] => 31-03-2020 ) Array ( [0] => 5 [id] => 5 [1] => 2020-2021 [fyear] => 2020-2021 [2] => 01-04-2020 [start_date] => 01-04-2020 [3] => 31-03-2021 [end_date] => 31-03-2021 )

Print total number of array i.e
1. we have number of 2 array.
2. I want to print count 2 inside loop.

Comment: In any particular language?  If so, which?

Comment: In PHP i need output.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I try to solve this but out will come outside the while loop. I need this output inside loop.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.